# What exactly does changing/setting a MINGWDIR environment variable do?

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, codeblocks

I am trying to install boost on code::blocks on a windows 8 computer. I am using mingw as my compiler because of a library I am using. What exactly does changing/setting a MINGWDIR environment variable do and how does this help me install boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many installations, programs, use this variable to quickly watch exactly where there is a certain environment.

For example:

It is easier to work with your own config batch files.
Also install Boost looking for "MINGWDIR".

Below is a **generic** example.(Nothing to do with boost).

```
@echo off
if [%MINGWDIR%] == [] goto environment_not_set
goto start_develop
:environment_not_set
echo
#############################################################################
echo Please adjust environment variables within this file:
set MINGWDIR=c:\mingw
echo
#############################################################################
rem instead of setting MINGWDIR here you could also set them
rem within the registry using the system control
:start_develop
set PATH=%MINGWDIR%\bin;c:\windows;
echo MINGWDIR = %MINGWDIR%
:end
pause
```

Comment: do I type that into the console?

Comment: Create, for example `environment.bat` paste code above into this file. Start the batchfile with a double click on the file `environment.bat`

Comment: ok, I ran that, how do I install boost to be looking for MINGWDIR?

Comment: You asked for the environment variable. This question has been answered **so I hope**. In **newer versions** boost no longer uses MINGWDIR. Now `msvc` is used `set toolset=msvc`. If you have problems with boost build please ask a new question. If you think the answer is not wrong on environment, mark it as answered.